# .NET7 console app - Serilog.Extensions does not contain Hosting

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I have a console app which I'm trying to configure for dependency injection, logging, etc.

I have the most recent nuget packages installed and referenced.

I realised I can't configure the builder to UseSerilog(), because Serilog.Extensions.Hosting also can't be installed.

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'Serilog.Extensions' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

csproj file is here:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The part that doesn't work (due to Serilog.Extension.Hosting not being installed):

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build())
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .CreateLogger();

 var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
                // fill in later 
        })
        .UseSerilog()          <---- IHostBulder does not contain a definition for UseSerilog()
        .Build();
```

Let me know what other questions I can answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install [`Serilog.Extensions.Hosting`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extensions.Hosting/5.0.1) package. From the [github](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting) page:

> Serilog logging for `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`.

Comment: This is the problem I have - trying to install Serilog.Extensions.Hosting gives me the error CS0234 I mention above.

Comment: @ITI7 can you please post a [mre] somewhere? I have successfully installed that package when reproducing the error. Try adding the package manually to csproj or install it using `dotnet add package` command.

Comment: @ITI7 what IDE do you use? Have you tried to reboot? Can you post full csproj?

Comment: As I say in the post, the error when installing it by Manager Nuget Packages is:
The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'Serilog.Extensions' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: When I try to install it from the console, I get a very strange outcome:
Error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

Comment: I have tried to insert it directly in csproj (see the code snippet above) but it doesn't work either :( I use Visual Studio 2022

Comment: @ITI7 _"I have tried to insert it directly in csproj (see the code snippet above)"_ - what code snippet? There is no such library in your project file.

Comment: @ITI7 _"I get a very strange outcome"_ - indeed strange. Are you under some (corporate) firewall? Also check your nuget config.